# Split regex to extract Strings of contiguous characters

Tags: java, regex, split, contiguous

Is there a regex that would work with [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to break a String into contiguous characters - ie split where the next character is different to the previous character?

Here's the test case:

```
String regex = "your answer here";
String[] parts = "aaabbcddeee".split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Expected output:

```
[aaa, bb, c, dd, eee]
```

Although the test case has letters only as input, this is for clarity only; input characters may be *any* character.

---

Please do not provide "work-arounds" involving loops or other techniques.

The question is to find the right regex for the code as shown above - ie only using `split()` and no other methods calls. It is not a question about finding code that will "do the job".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is totally possible to write the regex for splitting in one step:

```
"(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"
```

Since you want to split between every group of same characters, we just need to look for the boundary between 2 groups. I achieve this by using a positive look-behind just to grab the previous character, and use a negative look-ahead and back-reference to check that the next character is not the same character.

As you can see, the regex is zero-width (only 2 look around assertions). No character is consumed by the regex.

Comment: in `.net` character within the group i.e `(.)` is also included in the result..i wonder why it's not the case with `java`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: I guess there are some difference here and there between different languages. I have no idea to how achieve the same effect in .NET (or Ruby, since it also include capturing group in the result of split).