# split a string but dont split when character repeats java

Tags: java, string, split

How can I split a string, but when a character repeats, don`t split?

Like:

```
String a = "aHHHbYY";
String[] b = a.split("");
```

But I don't want to split every letter just the ones that don`t repeat.

Output would be like:

```
["a", "HHH", "b", "YY"]
```

Comment: Tried anything yet??

Comment: use a for loop, that will make things easier

Comment: Specify you question, before publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem can be solved easily with regular expressions. This could look like this:

```
String regex = "(?<=(.))(?!\\1)";
String a = "aHHHbYY";
String[] b = a.split(regex);
```

This gives the exact output you want. If you want a more detailed answer, take a look at this post:

[Split regex to extract Strings of contiguous characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596454/split-regex-to-extract-strings-of-contiguous-characters)

Comment: If your problem is solved, I would appreciate if you could accept this answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions as a solution. Here is a example for splitting and separating the chars and removing duplicates.

```
String input = "aHHHbYY";
String[] result = input.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1").split("");
```

will get you:

```
["a", "H", "b", "Y"]
```

Comment: In general, regular expressions aren't that easy to read and understand. But anyway it's always welcome to add some description to your answer. Apart from this, your `result` is `["a", "H", "b", "Y"]`, but the OP wants the array to be `["a", "HHH", "b", "YY"]`

Comment: @PascalSchneider Question was updated, after I answered. Lol.

Comment: If you take a look at the history of the post, my comment still applies.